# Notepad++ regex replace - how to remove this string

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to remove strings in the form of the following where `some-text` is a random text string.

```
$('#some-text').val();
```

I've tried various things but I think the `$` sign is messing things up since it's used in regex.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape some characters.
Try this -

```
\$\('#[^']*'\)\.val\(\);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex by escaping special chars:

```
\$\(.*\).val\(\);
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid escaping the special characters, you can use `\Q` - `\E` pair to surround the part where you want the regex engine to interpret literally:

```
\Q$('\E<your-regex>\Q').val();\E
```

Replace `<your-regex>` with your regex to match the selector, or whatever it is.